# python: Triacontagon Wheel

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, shapes

So I know how to make a triacontagon, but I'm trying to figure out how I can make it almost like a wheel (how to make the spokes essentially). If you could help that would be great!

```
import turtle
turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.up()
turtle.goto(0,150)
turtle.down()

numberOfSides = 30
lengthOfSide = 50
exteriorAngle = 360/numberOfSides
for i in range(numberOfSides):
    turtle.forward(lengthOfSide)
    turtle.right(exteriorAngle)
```

What I want it to look like:
[image: triacontagon with radii]

Comment: Have you already thought about how your turtle should move to draw the spokes? Think about where it is currently standing, and then draw with a pencil and paper where you would like it to go. Based on that, you will be able to figure out the pattern of motion needed to draw all 30 spokes (or 15 diameters).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
from turtle import *
circle(100)
left(90)
speed(10000000)
fd(100)
for i in range(60):
    fd(100)
    back(100)
    left(12)
```

This draws 31 spokes, so figure out 30, just make i 59.

picture:

[image]

Comment: You use nonsense arguments to turtle's `speed(10000000)` method in your various answer to OP's questions on SO.  I suggest you take a moment to read the documentation to `turtle.speed()` as it would be a loss to have your entire answer dismissed as silly due to a single nonsense line of code.  Particularly one that's optional, not relevant to your example, and can be left out.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get from where you are to where you want to be with the least amount of additional code:

```
import turtle

numberOfSides = 30
lengthOfSide = 75
exteriorAngle = 360 / numberOfSides

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.sety(-lengthOfSide)

for i in range(numberOfSides):
    turtle.circle(lengthOfSide, extent=exteriorAngle, steps=1)
    position = turtle.position()
    turtle.goto(0, 0)
    turtle.setposition(position)

turtle.done()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import turtle
import math
num=30
A=turtle.position()
side=50
x=(side/2)/math.sin(math.radians(180/num))

#x contains the length of one spoke of wheel
ext=90+(180/num)
turtle.setheading(0)
for i in range(num):
    turtle.forward(x)
    turtle.left(ext)
    turtle.forward(side)
    turtle.left(ext)
    turtle.forward(x)
    turtle.setheading((i+1)*(360/num))
 # the loop makes one triangle of polygon
```